# increase value for month and year in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I using this to get my month code value

```
@IBAction func increasemonth(_ sender: Any) {
     let currentmonth = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date())
     let increasemonth =  currentmonth + 1
     print(increasemonth) // 2            
}

@IBAction func decreasemonth(_ sender: Any) {            
    let currentmonth = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date())
    let decreasemonth =  currentmonth - 1              
    print(decreasemonth)// 0  
}
```

I want use this month to like 1,2,3....12 then year value is changed 2021 in increase button and also decrease month value like 1, 12,11....2 then year value changed to 2019

Answer (score 1):

You can use this following Date extention.

```
extension Date {

/// return yesterday date
var yesterday: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: self)!
}

/// return tomorrow date
var tomorrow: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: self)!
}

/// return day from date
var day: Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.day,  from: self)
}

/// return month from date
var month: Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.month,  from: self)
}

/// return year from date
var year: Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.year,  from: self)
}

/// return previous month date
var previousMonthDate: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: self)!
}

/// return next month date
var nextMonthDate: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: self)!
}

/// return true is it is last day of month
var isLastDayOfMonth: Bool {
    return tomorrow.month != month
}

/// return start date of month
var startOfMonth: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)))!
}

/// return end date of month
var endOfMonth: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1, day: -1), to: self.startOfMonth)!
}

/// return start date of last month
var startOfLastMonth: Date {
    let components:NSDateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: self) as NSDateComponents
    components.month -= 1
    return Calendar.current.date(from: components as DateComponents)!
}

/// return end date of last month
var endOfLastMonth: Date {
    var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: self)
    components.day = 1
    components.day! -= 1
    return Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
}

/// return last week date
var last7Day: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: self)!
}

/// return last month date
var last30Day: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -30, to: self)!
}

/// return last 6 month date
var last6Month: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -6, to: self)!
}

/// return last 3 month date
var last3Month: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -3, to: self)!
}

/// return date by adding numbner of days
func dateByAdding(days: Int) -> Date {
    return (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: .day, value: days, to: self, options: [])!
}

func startOfWeek(weekday: Int?) -> Date {
    var cal = Calendar.current
    var component = cal.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)
    component.to12am()
    cal.firstWeekday = weekday ?? 1
    return cal.date(from: component)!
}

func endOfWeek(weekday: Int) -> Date {
    let cal = Calendar.current
    var component = DateComponents()
    component.weekOfYear = 1
    component.day = -1
    component.to12pm()
    return cal.date(byAdding: component, to: startOfWeek(weekday: weekday))!
}

var dayOfWeek: Int {
    var dayOfWeek = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: self) + 1 - Calendar.current.firstWeekday

    if dayOfWeek <= 0 {
        dayOfWeek += 7
    }

    return dayOfWeek
}

var startOfWeek: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -(self.dayOfWeek + 1)), to: self)!
}

var endOfWeek: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 6), to: self.startOfWeek)!
}

var startOfQuarter: Date {
    let quarter = (Calendar.current.component(.month, from: self) - 1) / 3 + 1
    return Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self), month: (quarter - 1) * 3 + 1))!
}

var endOfQuarter: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 3, day: -1), to: self.startOfQuarter)!
}

var startOfYear: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: self))!
}

var endOfYear: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self), month: 12, day: 31))!
}


var hour: Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: self)
}

var minute: Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self)
}

var seconds: Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.second, from: self)
}

var nanosecond: Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.nanosecond, from: self)
}

func stringWith(format: String) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    return formatter.string(from: self)
}

public var currentTimeStamp: String {
    return "\(timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)"
}
}
```

you can use the above extension like below.

```
let date = Date()
print("month: \(date.month)") //you can do something with month
print("year: \(date.year)") //you can do something with year
print("hour: \(date.hour)") //you can do something with hour
```

Comment: thanks ...but let me know for my loop process .. same value append to my previous value month and  and that is increase  +1 or -1 till 12 only ..??

Comment: You need to put a condition that month > 0 && month <= 12

Comment: what about year ?? .. in Android  they provide ..on click increase/decrease  month along with year values

Comment: You need to add +1 or -1 as month in `Date` object.